# How should I configure Stockfish if I want it to play as a 2800 ELO player without the UCI_LimitStrength value?

Tags: engines, stockfish

Stockfish has so many parameters that I'm not sure which one I should change so that it has a strength equivalent to that of a human who has 2800 ELO, well that's one of my wishes, the other is to be able to play against Stockfish at its maximum potential (3600 ELO), it is clear that I will lose but I don't care, I just want to play, the specifications of my PC are as follows:

-4GB RAM

-CPU 4Cores/4Threads

-Only HDD

I have been testing with the Skill Level parameter however I am not sure if that is enough as I am not a very strong player to know if Stockfish is playing better than a GM.

Comment: If you just want to play, why use a computer when you have tens of thousands of humans out there?

Comment: Because I want to play specifically against Stockfish, besides there is no human with an ELO of 3600 points.

Answer (score 3):

So couple of issues off the cuff;

Do you have a particular version in mind?

Chess engines don't exactly have "ELOs". Chess engines are about calculation speed, calculation depth. They guestimate (at best) to determine a theoretical strength then measure against  other engines.

Stockfish 9 with 4 Cores is ~ 3200 "ELO"
Stockfish 12 similar rig I would argue is around that 3400-3600 "ELO" Mark.

The Reality; Playing solely against engines, at the highest level is ill advised for any development and engines are best used for position analysis (if that).

Comment: Good information especially the advice, the version of Stockfish I want to use is 12, and I think the focus of my question can also serve to setup the position analysis. The thing is that as I do not know the optimal configuration I could be using a mediocre level of Stockfish.

Comment: @talC just stick with stock. Its well optimised on default

Comment: So I only have to change the Skill Level value and nothing else?

Answer (score 1):

You can change the depth of the Engine, 10 depth is around 2400 ELO, and depth 18 is 3200 ELO.
The highest depth 99 is around 4050 ELO(approx. 4023 ELO)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This answer's correct, but I would like to see sources for how strong the engine is at fixed depth.